# How to link against msvcrt.dll instead of msvcr100.dll in VC++ 10.0?

Tags: visual-c++

Is it possible to link against VC6's MSVCRT.DLL in VC++10.0?

By default it seems to be linking with MSVCR100.DLL, but I don't want to redistribute yet another DLL (MSVCRT.DLL is already available in every OS that I support).

---

##### Edit

To clarify: my application is a pure C application that makes WinAPI calls. I do understand that doing C++ will require the C++ runtime, which is not bundled in Windows by default (and most probably has to match the compiler anyway). My question is about pure C usage, and only the CRT functions that exist in the earliest version of Windows that I'm targeting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not the VC6 runtime.  It's a system copy of MSVCRT.DLL that's bundled with Windows rather than Visual Studio.  Each new version of Windows gets a new version of MSVCRT.DLL, as you can see by checking the file sizes.

You can compile against the system copy of MSVCRT.DLL by using the Windows Driver Kit.  Note that this DLL is for use "only by system-level components."  What's a system-level component?  Well, a driver.  Or, for example, a text service:

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tsfaware/archive/2008/01/17/visual-studio-2008-issues.aspx
>
> If you're building a text service DLL ... I would recommend installing
>   the Vista (or XP) DDK and use the DDKWizard instead.  The DDK comes
>   with its own C/C++ compiler that uses the C Runtime Library that ships
>   with the OS (and won't cause problems with other applications) ...

More information:

> http://kobyk.wordpress.com/2007/07/20/dynamically-linking-with-msvcrtdll-using-visual-c-2005/
>
> A question arises, what does Microsoft do? They deploy their
>   applications to a variety of Windows environments. A look at Windbg’s
>   dependencies showed it’s using MSVCRT.DLL rather than one of the newer
>   CRTs. Microsoft’s new Network Monitor 3.1 also uses MSVCRT.DLL.
>   Windows Desktop Search is also using the old, trusty CRT.
>
> How can all these new applications be using the vintage CRT? They’re
>   not still using the antique, unsupported Visual C++ 6.0, are they?
>   Well, no. The answer is more complicated and can be found in the
>   Windows Driver Kit (WDK).

Update: The Windows 8 Driver Kit introduced a new MSBuild-based build system, which no longer links against the system copy of MSVCRT.DLL.  However, binaries built with the Windows 7 Driver Kit still work on Windows 8 and Windows 10.

MSVCRT.DLL is still shipped with Windows 10 for backward compatibility, so it carries a File version of 7.0.#####.  A component that is still being actively developed, such as user32.dll, carries a File version of 10.0.#####.

Comment: Thanks! The second link is amazing, it explains everything and provides a good solution to avoid bloatware!

Comment: using DDK to compile a GUI application is not a supported scenario.

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟: so Microsoft included ATL and the MFC and all the headers, libs and tools for UM applications "by mistake"? It *is* supported. Go try it. Admittedly the MFC and ATL versions are usually relatively old (e.g. ATL 7.1 for the 6001.18002 WDK). But they *are* included. Funny you accuse me of being in denial about that (comments on other answer).

Comment: Correction, ATL 7.0 is in 6001.18002, ATL 7.1 in 7600.16385.1.

Comment: 1 those are not complete libraries. 2 Microsoft said those are for writing driver applets and anything beyond that is not supported. 3 those have nothing to do with the c runtime (MFC DLLs already have version numbers and ATL is header only).

Comment: Simply untrue. Microsoft _does_ support, and has for quite some time supported, the creation of user mode code with the WDKs (`MFC_FLAGS` in `SOURCES` files, for example, or `ATL_INC_PATH` which defaults to `%DDKROOT%\inc` or `USE_ATL`, `USE_MFC` and **`USE_MSVCRT`** ... oh my). After all _several_ driver models are run from user mode and so it's practical to be able to use ATL and friends. If you think ATL is header only, you evidently don't know it in-depth. But don't let the provided facts dissuade you from your view.

Answer (score 19):

(you can find an executive summary, or TL;DR, at the bottom)

Important: This answer refers to official Microsoft toolchains *only*, not to something like the MinGW toolchain (GCC-based) which is also known to link against `msvcrt.dll`. But I doubt Microsoft would be inclined to support that toolchain anyway ;)

#### Short answer: no!

Don't even try using Visual C++ 2010 for the task.

There's an official and supported method: use a standalone WDK, if you need your application to link against `msvcrt.dll`!

You should *never* attempt to use a compiler toolchain that doesn't match the CRT headers and libs. Use the toolchains as Microsoft intended, not a patchwork you create. Don't mix and match. Use what's handed to you by Microsoft. But use that (and don't be afraid by the FUD).

The newest WDK which you can use to link against `msvcrt.dll` (7600.16385.1) uses `cl.exe` version 15.00.30729.207. This [corresponds](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/) roughly to the compiler that comes with Visual C++ 2008! Later WDKs will link against the CRT of the Visual C++ version *they require*.

The `msvcrt.dll` you'll find on, say Windows XP or Windows 7 is *not* the *original* DLL which was included with Visual C++ 6.0 (even the most updated version of VC6).

This has also been *correctly* stated in other answers. No surprises there.

However, the `msvcrt.dll` which you will find on modern systems *will*, contrary to what other answers suggest, allow programs that linked against the original VC6 CRT to continue to work. Even today. It's a contract. And the promotion of `msvcrt.dll` to a system DLL further validated that contract.

#### A little historical background

The toolchains used by Microsoft internally were somewhat similar to what the WDKs prior to the Windows 8 WDK provided. I will exclusively write about these and use the term WDK (or standalone WDK) uniformly, even when prior to the Vista WDK they were called DDK.

The good folks from [OSR](http://osronline.com/), who seem to have access to the Windows source code or people who do, confirmed during one seminar I attended some years back that the WDK used to be a trimmed down version of the toolchain used internally to build Windows around the time (~2005). Similar hints can be found [from MSFT's own Larry Osterman](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bwill/2004/06/22/how-well-do-you-know-your-microsoft-acronyms/) and [early works of Alex Ionescu on tinykrnl](https://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/Coffeehouse/189875-How-Windows-is-build-), the co-author of recent editions of "Windows Internals". BCZ likely alludes to `build -cZ`, a commonly used invocation with the WDKs I am describing here.

The reason it is interesting in this context is: all standalone WDKs allow you  to create executables that link against `msvcrt.dll` by default. For the standalone WDKs `msvcrt.dll` is *the* CRT, just like for Visual C++ 2010 that's `msvcr100.dll`.

One should also note that the toolchains were updated alongside the Visual Studio toolchains. For example in the 3790.1830 WDK `cl.exe` reports as roughly on par with Visual C++ 2003:

```
C:\WINDDK\3790.1830\bin\x86>cl /version
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 13.10.4035 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 1984-2002. All rights reserved.
```

And for the 6001.18002 WDK (latest to support Windows 2000!) as roughly on par with Visual C++ 2005:

```
C:\WINDDK\6001.18002\bin\x86\x86>cl/version
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 14.00.50727.278 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

For the 7600.16385.1 WDK it's on par with Visual C++ 2008.

**Standalone WDKs**

The WDK versions starting with the one for XP and up until (and including) Windows 7 SP1 did not require Visual Studio. They came with their own toolchain.

Versions prior to Windows XP required Visual C++ to build anything. If I remember correctly VC6 for the Windows 2000 DDK.

Versions starting from the Windows 8 WDK require Visual C++ again and integrate more tightly than ever with it (including wizards and even extensions for debugging and some driver-specific tasks). That's also the reason why when you use the respective WDKs, they will link to the CRT of the respective toolchain.

During the time of the standalone WDKs it was not unheard of - and that's the very reason for DDKWizard and [VisualDDK](https://sourceforge.net/projects/visualddk/) - that people tried using Visual Studio to wrap the WDK build process. Some even used the *unsupported* method that Microsoft recommended **against** and built their drivers with the Visual Studio toolchains. Those unsupported methods amount roughly to what you are trying. **So don't.**

Anyway, the build process using WDK's `build.exe` with `sources` and `makefile` and so on was cumbersome and limiting. For example to build from any source file outside the current directory or its parent directory, you'd have to write your own NMake rules. After all `build.exe` was a wrapper around an NMake-based build. Your local `makefile.inc` would get included by the global one provided by the WDK/DDK.

#### Why linking to `msvcrt.dll` is *officially* supported

As mentioned earlier, linking against `msvcrt.dll` is supported with the standalone WDKs.

This is perfectly fine to do as well. In fact the `USE_MSVCRT=1` statement in the `sources` file has exactly that effect. See [here](http://blogs.msmvps.com/kernelmustard/2005/11/04/building-win32-apps-with-build-exe-and-the-ddk/). Quoting from the 7600.16385.1 WDK documentation:

> **`USE_MSVCRT`**
>
> Use the `USE_MSVCRT` macro to instruct the Build utility to use the
> multithreaded runtime libraries in a DLL for your build.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> `USE_MSVCRT = 1`
>
> [...]
>
> **Note**  You should never list `Msvcrt.lib` or `Msvcrtd.lib` in `TARGETLIBS`. However, you can list `Ntdll.lib` in `TARGETLIBS`.

Why would Microsoft even offer this path if it were not supported by them? Correct, they wouldn't!

**As a matter of fact said WDKs (XP..7 SP1) have been using *the system DLL* `msvcrt.dll` as their CRT.**

#### Caveats

There's mainly one caveat. The way SEH is implemented has changed over time with newer Visual C++ versions. Since the toolchains from the standalone WDK correspond closely to specific Visual C++ version, they inherit the respective SEH handling.

For example when you use the Windows 7 SP1 WDK to target Windows 7 and with `USE_MSVCRT=1`, it statically imports `_except_handler4_common`. That function was not available on Windows Server 2003, for example. So trying to run such an application on versions of Windows prior to the *targeted* version *may* fail. So in such a case you are venturing into "unsupported territory" and all disclaimers apply. However, you have the option of using the method [outlined here](https://kobyk.wordpress.com/2007/07/20/dynamically-linking-with-msvcrtdll-using-visual-c-2005/), i.e. linking to `msvcrt_win2000.obj`, `msvcrt_winxp.obj` and `msvcrt_win2003.obj` (available in the Vista and 7 WDKs) to achieve the level of (binary) backward compatibility you desire.

Well, on the other hand, if you decide to set `WINVER=0x0601` you should also not be surprised to find that the resulting executable imports functions from kernel32.dll (or other system DLLs) which are not available on, say, Windows XP. So why expect different semantics with regard to `msvcrt.dll`?

**As another side-note:** even checked builds (commonly considered to correspond to debug builds) also link against `msvcrt.dll`, not its debug version counterpart! Because "checked" refers to the fact that assertions are left in; it does not refer to particular configurations of the CRT, such as "release" or "debug". The assumption that the unavailability of a debug build for `msvcrt.dll` in the standalone WDKs means it's somehow not *the* C runtime of those WDKs is plain and simple a misunderstanding of what *checked build* means.

There is another minor caveat. If you use, say, the Windows 7 WDK, to achieve linking against `msvcrt.dll`, you're using a toolchain unaware of developments *since* Windows 7. This includes import libraries, but also headers. So don't expect it to support features that were unavailable at the time it was released.

#### System DLL: `msvcrt.dll`

`msvcrt.dll` was promoted to the status of a system DLL some years ago, which means it comes included with the system (and can be relied on, *literally*) unlike other Visual C++ CRTs, for which you need to install the respective redistributable packages. Which is also the gist of the [blog post by Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140411-00/?p=1273) quoted in another answer.

Since the standalone WDKs (XP..7 SP1) default to linking to `msvcrt.dll` as their CRT, there's no objective argument against it. Of course *opinions* vary.

#### A "reply"

Unfortunately [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10168107) which has [changed a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10168107/revisions) since I first commented on it, perpetuates FUD and tries to pull quotes from purportedly authoritative sources out of context. It also links to original (MSFT) sources which - upon close inspection - do not support the statements for whose support they were linked.

---

> Microsoft's Raymond Chen blogged on this a few years ago. From his
> blog [Windows is not a Microsoft Visual C/C++ Run-Time delivery
> channel](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140411-00/?p=1273):
>
> > one DLL compatible with all versions of Visual C++ was a maintenance nightmare ... At some point, the decision was made to just give up and
> > declare it an operating system DLL, to be **used only by operating
> > system components**.
>
> Emphasis mine. Think again, are you really writing something that
> ships with Windows? Is it THAT difficult to add a supported file to
> your setup program or link the static version of CRT, instead of
> depending on a system component that Microsoft **gave up on compiler
> compatibility more than a decade ago**?

Okay, so February 2010 is more than a decade ago (time this answer was written: March 2016)? Because that's the release date of the 7600.16385.1 WDK, which **officially** supports linking against `msvcrt.dll`.

And the rest of Raymond's statements may match what Microsoft initially intended, but he even admits that they gave up on that and promoted it to a system DLL.

Also, it's quite dishonest to mix truly ancient history (Windows 9x) with recommendations in favor of using standalone WDKs, which don't even support Windows 9x. The historical background Raymond describes is pre-W2K and non-NT. The background I describe above refers to the NT lineage of Windows and I only know the standalone DDKs/WDKs (and newer) from practice, so I cannot tell how it was or was supposed to be prior to that.

All that said: his blog is *not* to be confused with *official documentation* from Microsoft, although a lot of gems can be found on his blog and I've been an avid reader for years.

And although *that* is more than a decade ago, the `msvcrt.dll` version information in Windows 2000 (SP4) says:

```
Description:    Microsoft (R) C Runtime Library
Product:        Microsoft (R) Visual C++
Prod version:   6.10.9844.0
File version:   6.10.9844.0
```

... contrary to Raymond's introductory statement.

Only with Windows XP did that change to:

```
Description:    Windows NT CRT DLL
Product:        Microsoft« Windows« Operating System
```

---

> It is amazing how many people are still in denial of this decision.

It's fair to assume after some previous comments that this is squarely aimed at me.

Well, I am not in denial of decisions made with the release of the Windows 8 WDK. But that doesn't "unrelease" the standalone WDKs which officially supported linking to `msvcrt.dll` nor does it "undocument" what can be found in their respective *official documentation*.

Hey, it's cool with me if you're in the luxurious position to only have to support Windows 7 or 8 and newer, or something along those lines. However, I *have to* support earlier Windows versions as well and so I'll make full use of the *official* tools provided by Microsoft for these Windows versions. Be that Visual C++ 2005 with the appropriate SDK integrated or be that a standalone WDK.

---

> Those people caused "a lot of grief for the Visual C++ product team"

This statement refers to the aforementioned [blog post by Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140411-00/?p=1273), but pulls Raymond's statements out of context, specifically out of temporal context. The grief was caused by people trying approximately what the asker wants to do - and worse: reaching into the guts/internals of `msvcrt.dll`. And that was pre-W2K. It was *not* (and would not be) caused by using an official toolchain like the standalone WDKs from Microsoft.

---

> The msvcrt version in modern versions of Windows has never been mentioned in the corresponding versions of Windows SDK.

While *modern* should be qualified, the use of "Windows SDK" suggests that it refers to all Windows SDKs after they were renamed from "Platform SDK". And I am inclined to readily believe that. But the poster is ignoring the standalone Windows WDKs (and prior to that DDKs) which not only mention it, but also use `msvcrt.dll` as their CRT. They *are* official toolchains from Microsoft aimed at both kernel and user mode development.

---

> Microsoft update the CRT DLL (for example, when releasing a Windows Media Player patch) using a current toolchain that may or may not be made public.

That's correct. `msvcrt.dll` keeps getting updated *because* it has been promoted to a system DLL. And that *is* the contract one can rely on when using the WDKs. They're not going to break applications built with their own toolchains, just because they're patching `msvcrt.dll`.

---

> You can count on them are not using the ancient WDK compiler and libs to build the msvcrt DLL in Windows

I'd not even be sure of that, but an **official** toolchain from 2010 isn't exactly something I'd call ancient. Besides, since Microsoft dropped support for XP and 2003 meanwhile, they only need to support Vista and onwards. That's bound to be easier with the latest Visual C++ version which *directly provide* the compiler and tools for the WDKs starting with the Windows 8 one.

> (why ancient? Because [the WDK team does not like people use their compiler to link against msvcrt either, and removed the loophole in version 8.0 to stop those "clever" people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166412/how-to-link-against-msvcrt-dll-instead-of-msvcr100-dll-in-vc-10-0/36189986#36189986)).

Oh really, does Doron actually say *that* at the linked forum post? Well, no:

> the win7 wdk build deployed successfully because you linked against
> the windows CRT (msvcrt.dll). **we don't want 3rd parties doing that
> *anymore***, so we removed that capability in the win8 wdk.  it still
> works for backwards compat. while it may deploy successfully, there
> may be whck logo checks that make sure you use the right CRT

(emphasis mine)

The statement is about a "political decision" (and an official one at that) by Microsoft to change their stance. The "anymore" in fact implies that this only changed with the Windows 8 WDK. The first modern WDK that integrates with Visual C++ again (since the Windows 2000 DDK). So since the WDK has been demoted from a standalone toolchain to an extension that integrates with a given Visual C++ version, the new requirements are no surprise at all.

It is, btw, also dishonest to argue based on the Windows 8 WDK and newer, when the suggestions regarding standalone WDKs, which use `msvcrt.dll` as their CRT, were prior to that policy change. It's also dishonest to mix the history that led to the promotion of `msvcrt.dll` to a system DLL with the era *after* it had been promoted.

---

#### Glossary

- CRT == C/C++ runtime
- 3790.1830 == Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1 (SP1)
  Driver Development Kit (DDK)
- 6001.18002 == Windows Driver Kit SP1 for Windows Server 2008/Vista
- 7600.16385.1 == Windows Driver Kit version 7.1.0 (Supporting Windows 7, Windows Vista, Windows XP, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2003)

#### TL;DR

Contrary to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10168107) it is perfectly fine to use Microsoft's own and unchanged toolchains, such as the standalone WDKs, which support linking against `msvcrt.dll` (XP..7 SP1) "natively". It's even documented in the documentation that comes with those toolchains (unless you decide to not install it or close your eyes :)).

You "only" *have to* make sure to target the correct Windows version when building (essentially the same as defining the correct `WINVER`). But the same can be said for other system DLLs (e.g. `kernel32.dll`, `user32.dll` ...).

**However,** using *any* Visual C++ since 2002 to link against `msvcrt.dll` [**is bound** to create trouble](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140411-00/?p=1273). Don't mix and match. Simply use the CRT matching those particular Visual C++ versions.

Answer (score 7):

An average "Petzold-style" Win32 program only needs a few functions out of msvcrt.dll. In my case, I often need the float-point formatting routines, like `_sntprintf()`. And it's unlikely that the functionality of such functions ever changes. For this reason, I created [an `msvcrt-light.lib` import library](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/%7Eheha/hsn/msvcrt-light.zip/) ([download](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/%7Eheha/hsn/msvcrt-light.zip)) as a replacement for the standard library which I include in the MSVC project.

For full-fledged C++ programs, `msvcrt-light.lib` may not be suitable at all. Use the DDK as stated above.

Comment: just FYI, you don't need to have those `.cpp` files, but they make it easier to create the import libs from a standard Win32 project. However, you can also use a simple makefile or a "make project" to instruct `lib.exe` to create those import libs without any C/C++ source file.

Answer (score 0):

This requires CRT compatibility across major compiler releases, which Microsoft tried to accommodate (e.g. added a VC5 heap to the VC6SP2 runtime) but eventually gave up on and introduced msvcrxx.dll that are in use today. If you look at the CRT source, you will find lots of #ifndef _SYSCRT, that's the difference between Microsoft's msvcrt.dll and the one used by your compiler when generating code.

Microsoft's Raymond Chen blogged on this a few years ago. 
From  his blog [Windows is not a Microsoft Visual C/C++ Run-Time delivery channel](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140411-00/?p=1273):

> one DLL compatible with all versions of Visual C++ was a maintenance nightmare
>   ...
>   At some point, the decision was made to just give up and declare it an
>   operating system DLL, to be **used only by operating system components**.

Emphasis mine. Think again is it THAT difficult to add a supported file to your setup program or link the static version of CRT, instead of depending on a system component that Microsoft **gave up on compiler compatibility more than a decade ago**?

It is amazing how many people are still in denial of this decision. Those people caused ["a lot of grief for the Visual C++ product team"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140411-00/?p=1273), and if you keep pissing them off, I won't be surprised if they piss you off sometimes like [what they did in Windows XP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/884538) that crashed a lot of VC6 apps. A lot of people did not follow Windows 2000 application developer guidelines and put settings/game saves in the Program Files folder. We all know what a good ending it is when Windows Vista was released.

By the way the dll is not VC6's. Using an old dll in the system would fail the  Microsoft’s Security Development Lifecycle automatically.  (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100607-00/?p=13793/#10020962). You don't realistically expect Microsoft use VC6 to compile its modern product, do you?

The msvcrt version in modern versions of Windows has never been mentioned in the corresponding versions of Windows SDK. Whatever compiler version or CRT lib version you use, it most likely won't match the majority of DLL versions on your customer's machine. Microsoft update the CRT DLL (for example, when [releasing a Windows Media Player patch](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/srd/2012/02/14/ms12-013-more-information-about-the-msvcrt-dll-issue/)) using a current toolchain that may or may not be made public. You can count on them are **not** using the ancient WDK compiler and libs to build the msvcrt DLL in Windows (why ancient? Because [the WDK team does not like people use their compiler to link against msvcrt either, and removed the loophole in version 8.0 to stop those "clever" people](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/67a6eec2-9f8f-4a23-a0ef-f0bf5bafc7fe/wdk-8print-monitorsunable-to-install-port-mon-on-windows-8?forum=wdk)).

Comment: `msvcrt.dll` has been promoted to the status of a system DLL several years ago. So you **can** count on it not breaking. If you couldn't, you also shouldn't rely on `kernel32.dll` or other system DLLs not breaking. Your statement was true prior to Windows XP and prior to Windows 2000 (with some patches applied). But these days it's wrong. And yes, I saw that your answer is almost four years old.

Comment: so you say because it becomes a system dll you are free to use undocumented interfaces from the dll? well that is not true. if what you’re doing is undocumented, it’s not guaranteed to keep working https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160308-00/?p=93123

Comment: so you're trying to tell us that the **C Runtime** is an  undocumented interface? Well, that's not true either.

Comment: Yes that is correct. The old dll from VC6 may be documented, but whatever in your system32 isn't, even if they share the same file name. You cannot count on it not breaking because Microsoft said it is not yours to use.

Comment: Incorrect! One **can** count on this not breaking. For one simple reason: *old programs* which linked against `msvcrt.dll` *continue* to work with the new ones. However - but that's a completely different matter and perhaps the cause of the confusion here (?) - if you build an application with a newer DDK/WDK to link against `msvcrt.dll` and you did _not_ specify the correct minimum OS you may end up with an executable that statically imports functions from `msvcrt.dll` introduced with XP. That's a matter of backward vs. forward compatibility though. The CRT interface is **documented/stable**.

Comment: As a side-note: the very fact that you can link against `msvcrt.dll` with the DDKs/WDKs between XP and 7 SP1, *proves* my point. This is a highly official toolchain from Microsoft.

Comment: The fact that some programs continue to work are merely coincidence. It is not part of Windows SDK or even part of Windows in certain versions and configurations, you can't count on it to exist at all. The fact that no corresponding msvcrtd.dll is ever made public and WDK version 8 corrected its behavior should tell you something.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately still incorrect. The reason why there is no `msvcrtd.dll` included is because a.) *that* was never promoted to be a system DLL and b.) because even up until the most recent versions of Visual C++ **the debug runtime has never been *redistributable***.

Comment: not redistributable means you got a copy but not allowed to redistribute it. not available means you don't even have a copy.

Comment: I know that. Is there also a conclusion to draw from that, or did you just want to get that out at last?

Comment: well I think it is enough to say Microsoft does not agree with you. If you want to discuss with me further I suggest to quote what Microsoft said about its future, not just what you observed from the past, because we are discussing future Microsoft behavior.

Comment: Microsoft agrees just fine. All the standalone WDKs between XP and 7 SP1 support linking against `msvcrt.dll`. All you need to take care of is to target the correct Windows version. Ignoring the WDK to "prove" your point is not very honest. And yes, I agree that in the future this is no longer the case, specifically *because* WDKs for Windows 8 and newer *require* a corresponding Visual C++ installation *again* (this was last the case for Windows 2000). But the existing standalone WDKs are alive and well and I use them regularly. Specifically the 6001.18002 WDK.

Comment: Still your observation. Don't put your words in Microsoft's mouth. Did the WDK team actually say anything about support the dll in the future? Apparently not. They removed it. "A maintenance nightmare" and "should only be by operating system components." are their opinions.

Comment: It's hopeless. Whatever. I'm not putting words in Microsoft's mouth, I am putting facts in your face. And you're really good at ignoring them. Also, the **opinion** of an MS employee on his blog is not MS' official stance on *anything*. Even your newest example citing the "WDK team" is bogus. As it refers to a **print driver**. Yes, that's right, a driver. We've been talking about usermode applications so far. You keep twisting an turning facts and try to quote people in wrong contexts. Just hopeless.

Comment: You are. I am putting Microsoft'd words in your face and you got nothing to contradict but undocumented behavior you observed.