# The procedure entry point _except_handler4_common could not be located in the dynamic link library msvcrt.dll

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, windows-xp, installshield

I am using "Microsoft Visual Studio" to work with an "MFC application".

I am using "Installshield" to create the setup file for this application.

I get a "setup.exe" file.

If I run this setup on a "Windows XP 32 bit" machine, the installation ends properly.

Yet, when I try to start the installed program, I get the message:

```
"The procedure entry point _except_handler4_common could not be located in the dynamic link library msvcrt.dll."
```

In debug mode, I can't find the moment the error occurs because whatever the breakpoint I put in the code, the message appears before reaching the breakpoint, I guess at the very beginning of the program execution...

Note: It works for Vista 32 bit and Seven 64 bit.

It appears lots of people do have the same problem but I couldn't find a solution for myself.

Can you help?
Thank you.

Comment: Msvcrt.dll was used by VC++ projects 15 years ago.  You cannot use them anymore unless you run them in a virtual machine.  You'll need to rebuild those projects.

Comment: He might be best served by refactoring and rebuilding, however, that DLL with that exported function is found on a stock installation of Windows 8.  See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the world of DLL hell and application dependency analysis.

I found that DLL on my Win8 machine in the SYSWOW64 (32bit System32 folder ) with version 7.0.9200.16384.  Looking at it using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) I can see it in fact exports the function you are looking for.

I also see on my InstallShield machine a merge module called MSVCRT.MSM that redistributes version 6.00.8797.0 of this file.  However when I look it using Dependency Walker, I see it has the exported functions _except_handler2 and _except_handler_3 but not _except_handler_4_common.

So therefore you need a newer DLL and that merge module won't help you.  Microsoft used to have this cool website called DLL Help Database that told you all the versions of a file and what shipped them but sadly they killed it.

BTW, I can also see that this DLL is installed with Windows these days.  Windows XP? I'm not so sure as I'd have to fire up a VM and look.

A couple possible resolutions:

1. Find out what SP or Hotfix of Windows fixes this and make it a dependency of your MSI.
2. Grab the DLL from a Win 8 machine and add it to your INSTALLDIR and deploy it privately.

One final note. This is either caused by the version of Windows XP comes with an old version of the DLL ( A related KB Article says it does )  or that a third party application whacked the DLL causing the problem.  Some more study is required here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I do not have a Win 8 machine available yet.
Can you tell me if I can download somewhere online a "msvcrt.dll"
which exports the "_except_handler_4_common" function
(a DLL which works under XP 32 bit).

Comment: What do you mean?
Some of our customers and prospects still have Win XP 32 bit machines.
We need the app. to work on XP 32 bit too...

Comment: I mean obtain the DLL from a Vista machine and try it on the XP machine as outlined in my answer.

Comment: I already tried several dlls including dlls from Vista with no success. Can I download a specific dll from my Microsoft account? Your dll works only for 64 bit machines, doesn't it?

Comment: I've told you what I can, it's up to you to investigate from here.

Comment: This function was introduced in Windows Vista. Since `msvcrt.dll` has been an OS component since Windows XP, no amount of installing or reinstalling of C/C++ runtimes is going to help with this. That holds true especially on systems where `msvcrt.dll` is a known DLL. I haven't bothered to check any old XP VM to see if it is; but if it were, it'd always take precedence over any other DLL in the search path as long as the DLL is exported by its base name `msvcrt.dll`.

Comment: @0xC0000022L you should add q&a necromancer to your profile. :)

Comment: @ChristopherPainter hehe, I think technically there's a badge for that even ... I'll consider it, though ;)

Answer (score 1):

I just installed the latest VS 2017 and was running into the same problem. I googled everything but couldn't find any solution, so I just defined it myself:

```
extern "C" int _except_handler4_common() {
    return 0; // whatever, I don't know what this is
}
```

Comment: It's a creative solution, but still not the correct one, since there's more to this function than your solution lets on ;)

Comment: lol, quite sure about that, but ain't nobody got time for that ;) i mean - if this would be an open source solution, we could dig into the details, but VS 2017... isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has a dependency which is not being satisfied on Windows XP. You might try using Dependency Walker to identify it, or you might check for known limitations. For example, Visual Studio 2012 doesn't support Windows XP until update 1 and a build option change - is that what you're using?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In this case, my colleague is still using MSVisual 2005.

Comment: No need to figure anything out. The error message is on spot and contains both function name not found and in which DLL it wasn't found.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you first try installing the MSVC Redist version 2008. That one does include the implementation of the missing function.

Comment: But it doesn't contain that function in a DLL named `msvcrt.dll`. And guess what, that's the error. Installing an arbitrary other DLL providing a function by the same name isn't going to solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

This post is old but I wanted to leave my solution since this problem was hell to me. My python app was working for Linux, Win7, 8 and 10 but WinXP refused to work with that message.

I was using py2exe to get an executable and it will put some DLLs along with the exe file.

Deleting some dlls from the exe's directory was the only thing that make the app work in XP and continue working in the other systems:

[ "POWRPROF.dll","IPHLPAPI.DLL","USP10.DLL", "DNSAPI.DLL" ]

Also distributing "Microsoft.VC90.CRT" directory along with the exe file, with it's manifest and DLL files.

I hope this will be useful for someone, since it took me weeks to figure it out.

(i know the OP wasn't working with python, but the error is just the same)

Comment: Arguably, if the installation of the VC90 runtime helped, your error message wasn't about `msvcrt.dll` _at all_, but about `msvcr90.dll` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

`msvcrt.dll` was made a system DLL during the release cycle of Windows XP (don't remember which exact patch level, I think SP1). You can inspect its version information for proof of that claim.

```
Description:    Windows NT CRT DLL
Product:        Microsoft« Windows« Operating System
```

This makes it and OS component. However, being an OS component doesn't mean it provides compatibility guarantees as you seem to expect them. Programs having been linked against older versions (incl. VC6) of `msvcrt.dll` are supposed to be compatible, but programs linked against *newer* versions may not work on an older OS that has an *older `msvcrt.dll` version*. The DLL has evolved and Vista introduced the function which wasn't found in this question.

However, being an OS component WDKs (DDKs) between XP and 7 SP1 contained everything to link against `msvcrt.dll` when building user mode projects (DLLs or programs). **There's but one catch: if the developer targets (or targeted) Windows Vista and newer**, the final `.exe` or .`dll` will inevitably contain a reference to `_except_handler4_common`. This will then cause the exact message from your question:

> The procedure entry point _except_handler4_common could not be located in the dynamic link library msvcrt.dll.

**In essence:** you can't do anything when you have a final product at hand. That function is referenced from the import table and that's a hardcoded reference tied to a particular DLL name. If you *are* the developer, you need to target the respective older DLL version (and consequently OS).

If you are interested in the technical details, please have a look at [my rather lengthy answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36189986/476371).

Remarks about some of the other suggested solutions:

- Installing *any* Microsoft C/C++ runtime version -- again, this `msvcrt.dll` is an OS component now and programs built with VC6 are likely to work on the new DLL version, but new programs linked against the newest DLL version may not work against older DLL versions at all
- Removal of `msvcrt.dll` from the directory in which the `.exe` resides *could* help on a system where `msvcrt.dll` is *not yet* a known DLL. On Windows 10, for example, it is a known DLL. That means if imported as `msvcrt.dll` -- i.e. without full path -- the known DLL will always take precedence.

PS: if you are using a newer WDK (starting with that one for Windows 8), you will probably get to link against one of the newer `msvcr1xx.dll` rather than `msvcrt.dll`. That's natural, because unlike the WDKs between XP and 7 SP1, the WDK no longer contains the toolchain (compilers, linkers) but instead expects to use those of a Visual C++ installation. *That's* what governs the compatibility with the C/C++ runtime in that case.
PPS: other articles mentioning this include [this](https://kobyk.wordpress.com/2007/07/20/dynamically-linking-with-msvcrtdll-using-visual-c-2005/) and [this](https://bearwindows.zcm.com.au/msvc.htm) one. Please note, that the WDKs also contained object files named something like `msvcrt_win2000.obj` to provide this symbol (and others), [because object files take precedence over `.lib` files during linking.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130109-00/?p=5613)

Answer (score -1):

The problem was probably because you might used a corrupted DirectX version on your Win XP. It happened to me as well because I randomly downloaded a DirectX setup which was corrupted and caused these. The solution I did was is I deleted all the files that has anything to do with directX from C:Windows/System32, deleted the directX from add/remove program as well and completely removed the whole registry key from regedit. `Local_machine/software/microsoft/DirectX...` What I did then was found a original values and keys for DirectX 9 on the net and made a new registry key.

The DirectX folder was once completely and originally back on regedit and it showed in dxdiag that the directX is installed.

In case you encounter crashes in the game, I suggest you to download .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 and then make a backup on your PC (If you're not using nVIDIA graphic cards like I do, I use ATI Radeon) and download nVIDIA PhysX system software driver and see if it works. (You need nVIDIA phydX drivers to run this game without crashes only if you use Win XP, the problem shouldnt encounter on Win 7) In case the drivers screw up your PC (The nVIDIA PhysX one) you will be able to restore your old PC function before those drivers (If you made a backup of your PC, I suggest using Acronis Boot for backups) it means you're totally out of luck if you're not able to get the nVIDIA PhysX on ur for example, ATI graphics on Windows XP, because without nvidia physx, on Win XP, Metro wont run, while on Win 7 / Vista / 8 it should.

Comment: I didnt notice this was not about Metro, so ignore the last few lines in the answer, it was about Metro 2033. But in case you might wanted to play the game, the rest few lines in the answer will be helpful to help you run the game smoothly.

Answer (score -2):

This problem persists to every software or game that requires Windows 7 or 8 or Vista but is tried to be run on Windows XP. So if you want to resume or start your program you need to upgrade your Windows to 7 or 8 or Vista as per the system requirements of the program.

Comment: -1: I do compile software under Windows 7 that runs fine on windows XP. If I could put -2 for the suggestion of upgrading I would do it: on most situations (but home fuddling) this is not an option. A virtual machine could be a better suggestion.

Comment: @Zac the statement, however, is perfectly true. Yes, you can build software on a more recent Windows version to target an older Windows release. However, the developer needs to take care of that then. If the developer was careless, you get the symptom the inquirer was puzzled about. But I can understand your annoyance at the suggestion of having to upgrade.

Answer (score -2):

I've spent the last 8 hours picking my code apart with this exact same error and it turned out to be a line of code in my application, specifically a check for IPv6 support in the OS:

```
conf.IPv6Disabled = !(Socket.OSSupportsIPv6);
```

- I commented that line out and voila, error disappeared.

Comment: is this supposed to be an answer? does op need to comment the exact same line as yours? and how should we know what conf and Socket refer to? this is non sense

Comment: yes it is supposed to be an answer - the call to check if the socket supports ipv6 in windows xp throws this exact error. "Socket.OSSupportsIPv6" is a boolean in the .net framework.