# How does Windows find where to dynamically link functions at load

Tags: windows, dll, exe, portable-executable, coff

I've been trying to learn about the [PE file structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format), and I compiled the following short program to examine the output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_5() {
    return 5;
}

int main() {
    int five = get_5();
    fputc(five, stdout);
    return five;
}
```

This uses the `fputc` function, which needs to be linked in from a .dll file. I compiled this in MSYS using `gcc -o program.exe program.c`.

When I look in the resulting executable's `.idata` section, it shows that it imports `fputc` from `msvcrt.dll`. It includes a name hint that I think is used to find where to link it within the .dll.

My question, however, is how does Windows then use this information to find where in the .dll to take the function? When I look inside `msvcrt.dll`, it does not contain a `.edata` section, which I thought is where information for exporting symbols is located. If there were an export table, I would assume the program loader looks through the ordinal and/or name pointer tables in the export section to get a pointer to the requested function. So, without an export table, how do the hint and name help to find the location of the function?

Comment: Please confirm **exactly** which `gcc` you're using. To my knowledge, only the MinGW port of `gcc` links to `msvcrt.dll`

Comment: Also, have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166412/how-to-link-against-msvcrt-dll-instead-of-msvcr100-dll-in-vc-10-0

Comment: @Dai From the MSYS2 console, `which gcc` results in `/mingw64/bin/gcc`

Comment: Other C runtime DLLs also seem to not contain, such as `ucrtbase.dll`, so the same question remains

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an explanation. While the .dll's do not contain a `.edata` section, they contain an image data directory entry for an export table in their optional header, which points to data in the `.rdata` section that is in the same format as a `.edata` section would have. Though I am still unclear on when a file would have an actual `.edata` section and would it would just have export data in `.rdata`. I imagine the same is true for imports, as well.